# 'отсутствие имеет место' -- лексическая ошибка?

Tags: грамматика

> В романе имеет место отсутствие ясно выраженной сюжетной линии.

Есть ли в этом предложении лексическая ошибка? Возможно некорректно говорить что *отсутствие имеет место*?

Comment: Полное отсутствие всякого присутствия... :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ошибки нет, «имеет место» — просто формальный оборот. В менее формальной речи всё это можно заменить на «нет ясно выраженной сюжетной линии», но структура формальной речи более жёсткая. Это позволяет быстрее классифицировать, например, здесь роман подпадает под «отсутствие ясно выраженной сюжетной линии». Такую формальную речь часто можно услышать от юристов, после «имеет место» у них часто следует конкретная выдержка из закона.

Answer (score 6):

Корректно, но слишком многословно. Мне кажется, сейчас это будет воспринято как тонкая пародия на чрезмерно формальный язык юристов и, в особенности, чиновников и государственных служащих. Также людей, которые пишут длинные и скучные статьи сложным языком. Явной пародией будет "отсутствие присутствия".

Обычно в научном и публицистическом стиле речь формальная, но НЕ совпадает полностью с языком официальных документов. По своему опыту скажу, что она, как правило, более живая и носит отпечаток личности автора и его манеры речи. При этом формулировки стремятся к точности, а построение предложений — к прямому следованию за логикой автора (для чего и используются зачастую инверсия и пассивы). Поэтому "имеет место отсутствие", наверное, не совсем из этого стиля.

Comment: Скорее "наличие отсутствия". В Википедии статья о [небытии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9D%D0%B5%D0%B1%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B5) есть такой пассаж: "Таким образом, возникает парадокс наличия абсолютного отсутствия."

Comment: @Artemix Не совсем понял, к чему. Про то, что в "серьёзном" стиле скорее уместно "наличие отсутствия"? Но, думаю, даже такое сочетание за пределами философских текстов (где точная формулировка о несуществовании дефиниции бытия в небытии действительно важна) будет звучать помпезно и смешно — то есть, когда "наличие отсутствия" используется просто в смысле "отсутствует", "нет".

Comment: Это по поводу "отсутствие присутствия". "Наличие отсутвия" довольно часто употребляется в ироническом смысле, а оказывается его источник - философские тексты.